# Matching up to the three occurrence in Regex

Tags: python, regex

This is my syntax regex:

```
(SL [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|\
(SL [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|\
(SL [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][0-9[0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9])
```

This is an expression

```
SL 5123 5016 test abcd SL 5445C 297741 eff SL 1288C 8709N5
```

I need:

- SL 5123 5016
- SL 5445C 297741
- SL 1288C 8709N5

syntax regex don't work. Where is mistake?

Where I use my syntax I get only two result

- SL 5123 5016
- SL 5445C 297741

but I need three or more.

Please help me.

Comment: A regex must be a string (that is, in "quotation marks"). Please write the exact Python string that you used. Also, provide the code that "_don't work_". We should be able to run your code and reproduce your error.

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/ to debug it.

Comment: See [`SL \d{4}(?: \d{4}|[A-Z] \d{4}(?:\d{2}|[A-Z]\d))`](https://regex101.com/r/UP5PTr/1). Actually, you have a typo, `[0-9][0-9[0-9]`  must be `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` in the third alternative. If you add `]`, [it will work](https://regex101.com/r/9lAkRh/1).

Comment: Typo `[0-9[0-9]` will only match 1 digit. Change it to `[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: Reduces to this [(SL \d{4} \d{4})|(SL \d{4}\[A-Z\] \d{6})|(SL \d{4}\[A-Z\] \d{4}\[A-Z\]\d)](https://regex101.com/r/dMeiDs/1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not only `SL\s[A-Z\d]{4,6}\s[A-Z\d]{4,6}`:

```
import re
_str = "SL 5123 5016 test abcd SL 5445C 297741 eff SL 1288C 8709N5"
result = re.findall( r"SL\s[A-Z\d]{4,6}\s[A-Z\d]{4,6}", _str )
# ['SL 5123 5016', 'SL 5445C 297741', 'SL 1288C 8709N5']
```

---

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/nPb2UA)

---

[Regex Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/mrzs2H/3)